# Using "could" when giving direction

Tags: modal-verbs

Today someone asked me how to get to a place via bus. I only knew the train route so I tried to tell her that she could(?) use the train instead.

This is an excerpt of the conversation:

Do you know which bus goes to entertainment center?
Me: You could use the train, entertainment center would be the last stop.

What I meant was to suggest the train instead. Is this the correct way of saying it? If this is wrong, what is the correct way of saying it?

Comment: You used *could* correctly here. Though "entertainment center" needs an article: "*the* entertainment center*".

Comment: It's ***A*** correct way to use it, anyway. There are many ways to be indirect, and modals feature in many of them.

Comment: @JohnLawler Did you see the question about putative and emotional *should* vs tense a couple days ago? An interesting question about modals.

Comment: I think I saw something that used some of those terms; but I don't recall details.

Comment: 'Take the train' is idiomatic English for travelling on it as a passenger; 'use the train' isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your use of *could* is just fine.

Dan Bron is right that "entertainment center" probably needs an article: "the", if there is one unique one, or "an", if there are many interchangeable ones.

Another possibility is that Entertainment Center (capitalised) is the name of a building, region, location, or terminus, (such as Angel, Elephant and Castle, or Ocean Terminal), in which case there is no article (but capitals are required if written).

Answer (score 0):

If "modal" went right over your head, try this:  "Could" is better than "can", because it conveys the uncertainty of the action—the other person might or might not choose to take the train. (If you had known the train was faster and cheaper than the bus, you might have said "should", but since you weren't sure whether the train was a better option, phrasing as you did leaves the choice open to him—taking the train is a possibility, but you're not necessarily recommending it.)
By the way, in spoken English, stressing the word COULD emphasizes that that option is his to choose.